# How to turn off word wrap in iTerm2?

Tags: unix, terminal, iterm, iterm2

How to turn off word wrap in iTerm2? Is there a specific command to do so or in the preferences? I am trying to avoid having the text run down to the next line. I would rather scroll side to side.

Comment: add `tput rmam` in your ~/.bash_profile [applicable in all the bash sessions]

Answer (score 84):

lifted directly from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210666/115119

Props to [@michid](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/13158/michid)

**Disable line wrapping:**

```
tput rmam
```

**Enable line wrapping:**

```
tput smam
```

Comment: this setting doesn't seem to stick for me

Comment: this just discards everything after the end of the line, in the OP's words "I would rather scroll side to side"

Comment: @cz question is "How to turn off word wrap in iTerm2?". As you noted, OP says "I **would rather** scroll side to side" not "AND scroll side to side". So I'd disagree with your downvotes.

Comment: @MikeD > rather; You should make a note of this in your answer.

Comment: @MikeD He obviously meant as opposed to the default wrapping behavior... How on earth could he have meant instead of the behavior introduced by your answer _before you posted it_?

Comment: Thanks. It's not about the OP! This is a form of crowdsourced journalism, searched years later by those in need. This answer is exactly what I needed. For example, the Unison command line file sync program produces very long lines, and one can ignore the tails. If one lets these lines wrap, it is much harder to get the gist of the information presented. Using "tput rmam" in my wrapper script, I don't have to expand my terminal to full screen every time I run Unison.

Answer (score 29):

It appears that [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/) does not have the ability to turn off word wrap.  There is an open issue ([iTerm2 issue #1790](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/1790)) reported to "Provide toggle to turn on/off line wrapping".

The description of that issue reads:

> Looks like a conversation was had in the Google Groups about this but no one ever actually filed a feature request.
>
> http://groups.google.com/group/iterm2-discuss/browse_thread/thread/e0f4e9b552d8acd4
>
> In general I don't like having horizontal scrollbars and prefer to have the lines wrap, but there are occasions...such as looking at long stack traces, that I'd rather just have sequentially indented lines line up and just be forced to scroll to the right to expose all the details. To accomplish this task now, I end up making the text incredibly small so I can read stack traces lined up, but even that doesn't always work.

In October, 2014, the creator of iTerm2 commented regarding the feature request to toggle word wrap, "I'd like to do this but it's a lot of work, so feel free to send a pull request, but don't be [a jerk]."

In April, 2015, the milestone for the feature request was changed to "Future Release".

Comment: I recommend using `less -S`, which allows you to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Thanks @George ! As it turns out, my main use case is in the mysql shell, where I can do `pager less -S` to allow horizontal scrolling of output results. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Oh nice, did not know about `less -S`. It turns out you can use that git logs too: `git config --global core.pager 'less -S'`

Answer (score 3):

For me, my issue was purely down to the configuration of my PS1 - not what I had originally expected!

The key for me was surrounding the following with any characters that wouldn't be printed as in your prompt - such as encoding colours. Sourced from https://linoxide.com/how-tos/change-bash-prompt-variable-ps1/

`\[` This sequence should appear before a sequence of characters that don’t move the cursor (like color escape sequences). This allows bash to calculate word wrapping correctly.
`\]` This sequence should appear after a sequence of non-printing characters.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! This was my issue too