# iTerm2 : Path into PS1 prompt is broken (\n) on different lines when it is too long

Tags: terminal, command-prompt, iterm2, ps1

I am using iTerm2 on MacOS Catalina. Here is my `PS1` into `~/.bashrc`, using a function `ps1` :

```
function ps1 {
        # PROMPT SECTION
        BLUE='\[\033[0;34m\]'
        LIGHT_CYAN='\[\033[1;36m\]'
        DEFAULT='\[\033[0m\]'
        PURPLE='\[\033[0;35m\]'
        LIGHT_PURPLE='\[\033[1;35m\]'
        LIGHT_GREEN='\[\033[0;32m\]'
        PINK='\[\033\[0;31m\]'


        # \! - History number of last command
        # $? - Exit value of last command
        # \t - Exit time of last command
        # \w - Current directory (relative)

PS1="$PURPLE|$DEFAULT$LIGHT_GREEN\u@$DEFAULT$LIGHT_CYAN\h$DEFAULT$PURPLE|$DEFAULT\t$PURPLE|$DEFAULT$LIGHT_PURPLE\w$DEFAULT$PURPLE|$DEFAULT "
}

ps1
```

The issue happens when I have long path, it seems to  be broken on second or third line like this:

[image]

I tried to increase the number of columns (to 1000) into `iTerm2 -> Preferences` but it doesn't seem to fix this issue.

I can't see where the error comes from. What might be wrong?

```
  fab@astro|13:12:32|~/Phd_2019_2020/Travail_2_faire_varier_Omega_DE_sur_CAMB_et_regarder_si_les_P_k_changent_21_Octobre_2019/Main_Directory_Work/TSAF_lvl_up_Derivatives_15_points_on_Cl_stabilite_Code_is_surel
y_VALIDATED_for_15_points_derivatives_AND_After_trying_to_solve_the_pathologic_zone_1e-5_TO_1e-2_13_Novembre_2019/Test_FAIRE_VARIER_TOUS_LES_PARAMETRES_AVEC_les_2_pas_2e-2_et_1e-1_AVEC_Takabird_SECONDE_TENTATIVE_AVEC_LA_VAR        IATION_de_wde_EN_FLAT_DANS_Camb_launcher_6_DECEMBRE_2019/CAMB_der_3_pts/fortran|
```

### Update

Solution finally found on [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376966/path-into-ps1-prompt-is-broken-n-on-different-lines-when-it-is-too-long).

Comment: @Rob But I couldn't illustrate the issue with text, it is difficult to reproduce, so that's why I used an image. Regards

Comment: Your image **is** text. How can you not illustrate the problem?!

Comment: @Rob I talk about the third line of prompt path which is broken like if there were a '\n' character.

Comment: I don't understand the `broken`  can you point out where in the image , or which specific character

Comment: @JerryZhou the broken part is visible on the part : `...AVEC_LA_VAR        IATION_de_wde_EN...` . I must precise that I also use grc to colorify my terminal, maybe it could come from this but not really convinced by that.

Comment: oh, I see, it's not an error, it's just display long text, it's break when possible (I think in this case it meet the first space), and the break rule sometime related to the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping the word-wrapping on iTerm2 is still an [open feature request](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/1790). So I'm afraid that if your line is too long, it'll get wrapped automatically anyway.

However, you could build your PS1 such that the line won't overflow by trimming the path down.

For that, you'd need the command `tput cols` to get the number of columns on your terminal if you want to do it manually, or just use one of the answers in [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17723/trim-the-terminal-command-prompt-working-directory).

If you are open to changing your shell from bash to zsh, a lot of thems in zsh trim the paths so that they don't overflow the line.

[image: An example of zsh trimming paths]

Another solution given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954083/how-to-turn-off-word-wrap-in-iterm2) would be to use the commands `tput rmam` to discard output that overflow, then re-enable wrapping with `tput smam`